# AngularJS get compiled route URL on routeChangeStartEvent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a recently visited menu in my angularJS app but I can't seem to find a good way to get the compiled URL `routeChangeStart` event, its only the template.

My code looks like:

```
       $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

            if ($route.current && $route.current.$$route && $route.current.$$route.controller){

                // only show 5
                if($scope.previousLocations.length == 5){
                    $scope.previousLocations.pop();
                }

                var title = $route.current.$$route.title, 
                    hasTitleAlready = false;

                // only add them once
                angular.forEach($scope.previousLocations, function(obj){
                    if(obj.title == title){
                        hasTitleAlready = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if(hasTitleAlready){
                     $scope.previousLocations.push({
                        title: title,
                        link: 'the compiled link here'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

and my template looks like:

```
 <ul class="recent-view">
       <li ng-repeat="loc in previousLocations"><a href="{{loc.link}}">{{loc.title}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

anyone got any good ideas on how to accomplish this cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`$location`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)?

From the documentation:

> #### When should I use $location?
>
> Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser.

Comment: $location is the 'new' route not the one I'm trying to preserve.

Comment: Is there a better event I should listen to that would show location before the change?

Comment: @amcdnl No, you should simply cache the value and use it when you need it.